# Positive synonym for "rebellious"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What's a more positive way of saying that someone is "rebellious" or doesn't like to conform to rules or conventions? Synonyms like "defiant" and "recalcitrant" seem too negative.

I want to complete the sentence:

> "Like any ______ teenager nowadays, I dislike following imposed rules, and I want to follow my own path."

Comment: _Revolutionary_ is the usual opposite in that dimension. Revolutions succeed, but rebellions fail. And history is written by the winners.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I would like an adjective to describe a person... revolutionary doesn't strike me as a word that would fit in the context "Like any revolutionary teenager, I don't like to follow the rules."

Comment: [Independently-minded](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/independently-minded) - *self-reliant and seeking autonomy.*

Comment: "Rebellious" isn't positive in itself?  It seems the connotation is pretty subjective: those who think following rules (or making other people follow them :-)) is good will see it as negative; those of us who value independence of spirit will see it as positive.

Comment: How about a Palinesque *Maverick*??

Comment: I would suggest "strong-willed".

Comment: I don't think your example sentence needs an additional adjective. "*Like **any teenager** nowadays, I dislike following imposed rules, and I want to follow my own path*" sounds about right to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about *free-spirited*?

Dictionary.com:

> [*free-spirited*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/free-spirited?s=t):
>   acting independently or somewhat irresponsibly

Your example:

> I want to complete the sentence: "Like any *free-spirited teenager*
>   nowadays, I dislike following imposed rules, and I want to follow my
>   own path."

*Free-spirited* seems a positive way of saying that someone is "rebellious" or doesn't like to conform to rules or conventions.

Answer (score 4):

> #### Independent
>
> **adjective**
>
> 1. not influenced or controlled by others in matters of opinion, conduct, etc.; thinking or acting for oneself:
>      *an independent thinker.*
>
> 4 . not dependent; not depending or contingent upon something else for 
>   existence, operation, etc.
>   5 . not relying on another or others for aid or support.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/independent?s=t))

If someone is independent then they are happy to do things by themselves.
On the other hand, this doesn't connote rebelliousness, only independence.

Comment: _Independent_ is what I would have said; +1.

Answer (score 1):

I particularly like the second sense of *transgressive*:
"of or relating to fiction, cinematography, or art in which orthodox cultural, moral, and artistic boundaries are challenged by the representation of unconventional behavior and the use of experimental forms." ([Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transgressive).)

It may have a negative tinge like the other words you ruled out, but I still find it applicable, considering that many people who resist conformity feel some satisfaction when they knowingly transgress a rule or limit which they believe to be arbitrary and confining.  (They like being "bad".)

I think etymology supports a more neutral/positive usage as well: *trans-* (across) + *gressus* (to walk, go).  Simply walking across the established lines of social custom.

Comment: Now having seen your edited question with the sentence you wish to complete, I agree with the last commenter that "independent-minded" is a pretty good fit.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage and thank you for your answer. One minor thing: You seem to be quoting a dictionary definition for *transgressive,* can you please [edit] your question to provide a link or citation of the source? Also note that answers posted as comments are free game for being posted as an answer by somebody else. So, if you agree with the comment you mention, feel free to advocate it in a separate answer in a similar fashion as this one (i.e., elaborating why you think it is a good choice and quoting dictionary definitions).

Comment: Thanks for the tip to credit my source (which I should have already known to do!)

Answer (score 1):

How about ["freethinking"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freethinking), or ["nonconformist"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonconformist)?

Personally, I am quite fond of "freethinking" as it implies reason without dogma, meaning that such a person would follow rules if they made sense and not just because they were told to obey.

Answer (score 0):

A term that can be used affectionately is '[feisty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feisty)' (MW, definition 2).

> having or showing a lively aggressiveness "the movie's feisty heroine"

It can be applied to people of any age, as the examples on the linked page show:

> ...Frank P. Zeidler, a feisty octogenarian...
>
> She never tired of hearing anecdotes from her childhood, and she particularly liked to hear how feisty she had been...
>
> Even her opponents admire her feisty spirit.

Answer (score 0):

> **independent-minded teenager**

Unfortunately I don't know a great way of documenting this.  [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/independent-minded) has a bunch of quotes, and a google search for the exact phrase "independent-minded teenager" will get you 13,600 hits (but then, so will many other phrases).  Still, in my experience, this is the standard euphemism for *rebellious teenager*.

Answer (score 0):

**[Iconoclastic](https://quizlet.com/295251743/smart-words-6-flash-cards/)**.

“Characterized by attack on cherished beliefs or institutions.”

Comment: Hi Shelby, welcome to EL&U. If you quote someone else's words, it's essential that you make this clear (eg using quotation marks or blockquote formatting) and *acknowledge the source*. It's not only polite to give the original author credit, it also avoids the more serious charge of **plagiarism**. I urge you to [edit] your post accordingly, and add a link and a brief explanation as to *why* this word suits the context.

Comment: @Chappo, I don’t invest much effort in data stored on centralized controlled databases (because it’s an inherently corrupt paradigm). I added the quote marks and upvoted your _pedantic_ comment. I’ll make the effort when my effort is recorded on a decentralized database that nobody controls (i.e. a blockchain). You realize that on a decentralized ledger, nobody can remove submitted content nor enforce such pedantic rules. Of course individual nodes can refuse to host/serve such content, but if there’s even one dissenter then the content lives forever. Please note fair use doctrine in copyright

Comment: Shelby, you have an interesting POV that I have some (slight) sympathy for. On the other hand, how can I tell whether your unsubstantiated opinion on the meaning of *iconoclastic* is correct? If you're an iconoclast, there's a higher probability that your  answer is deliberately misleading. Why would you post on our site if you find our standards unacceptable? Is that *recalcitrance* or *defiance*? At what point does it veer towards *vexatious* or *antisocial*?

Comment: @Chappo I like(d) your reply. Oh it’s quite substantiated. Just Google search my quoted string and it will pull up the source. I posted here, so that I can remember to scrape my work and move it to the decentralized ledger replacement I’m working on. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

"Individualistic" is also a good one for this instance:

Adj- 1. characterized by individualism; independent and self-reliant.
synonyms:   unconventional, unorthodox, atypical, singular, unique, original, nonconformist, independent, individual, freethinking."
2.marked by or expressing individuality; unconventional.
"her work is quirky and genuinely individualistic..."

Individualism is also a philosophical school of thought, so imparts some intellectual credibility, too.

Comment: Please tell us where that text that isn't yours comes from.

Comment: As tchrist says, can you  please provide evidence in the form of references to back up your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Something assertive, as in

*assertive*

> Of the nature of, or characterized by, assertion; declaratory, affirmative; positive, dogmatic

It's true 'assertive' does not denote 'rebellious' but someone who is assertive is not wont to 'conform to rules or conventions' just because they are there.

You could use self-assertive, but the *self* part is provided by *I*.

I do like

**self-asserting**

> insisting on one's own rights or claims; egoistic; assuming.

Most teens are wrapped up in their own world, so this seems appropriate. Someone who asserts themselves onto the world is not likely to be prone to conformity.

Or, you could forego the use of any adjective. First adjectives tend to weaken writing because they suggest nouns cannot do their job on their own. Second, isn't every teen one who 'dislike[s] following imposed rules, and [who] want[s] to follow [his/her/their] own path.'?

Definitions from the *Oxford English Dictionary*, online, available through susbcription.